# LDAP change user pass on client

Tags: ldap, openldap

I am trying to allow ldap users to change their password on client machines. I have tried pam every which way I can think of `/etc/ldap.conf` & `/etc/pam_ldap.conf`, as well. At this point I'm stuck.

> Client: Ubuntu 11.04
>   Server: Debian 6.0

The current output is this:

```
sobrien4@T-E700F-1:~$ passwd
passwd: Authentication service cannot retrieve authentication info
passwd: password unchanged
```

`/var/log/auth.log` gives this during the command:

```
May  9 10:49:06 T-E700F-1 passwd[18515]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "sobrien4"  does not exist in /etc/passwd
May  9 10:49:06 T-E700F-1 passwd[18515]: pam_ldap: ldap_simple_bind Can't contact LDAP server
May  9 10:49:06 T-E700F-1 passwd[18515]: pam_ldap: reconnecting to LDAP server...
May  9 10:49:06 T-E700F-1 passwd[18515]: pam_ldap: ldap_simple_bind Can't contact LDAP server
```

`getent passwd |grep sobrien4` (note keeping short since testing with that account, however it outputs all ldap users):

```
sobrien4:Ffm1oHzwnLz0U:10000:12001:Sean O'Brien:/home/sobrien4:/bin/bash
```

`getent group` shows all ldap groups.

`/etc/pam.d/common-password` (Note this is just the most current, I have tried a lot of different options):

```
password   required   pam_cracklib.so retry=3 minlen=8 difok=3
password   [success=1 default=ignore] pam_unix.so use_authtok md5
password   required   pam_ldap.so use_authtok
password   required   pam_permit.so
```

Popped open wireshark as well, the server & client are talking.

I have the password changing working on the server. I.E. the server that runs slapd, I can log in with the ldap user and change the passwords. I tried copying the working configs from the server initially and no dice.

I also tried cloning it, and just changing ip & host, and no go. My guess is that the client is not authorized by ip or hostname to change a pass.

Pertaining to the slapd conf, I saw this in a guide and tried it:

```
access to attrs=loginShell,gecos
      by dn="cn=admin,dc=cengineering,dc=etb" write
      by self write
      by * read

access to *
          by dn="cn=admin,dc=cengineering,dc=etb" write
      by self write
      by * read
```

So ldap seems to be working okay, just can't change the password.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to allow auth-bind'ing for it to work. By this, I mean the user connects to the ldap (or pam proxies) and presents his/her credentials. If the ldap server likes what it sees, the authbind succeeds and PAM knows thay your user/pass pair is correct. Please see the example [in zytrax's book](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch5/step2.html)

Adjust your ACL to have a section similar to

```
# ACL1
access to attrs=userpassword
       by self       write
       by anonymous  auth
       by group.exact="cn=itpeople,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com"    write
       by *          none
```

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this exact same problem before; in order to resolve this, I needed to remove `use_authtok` - this allowed us to then change user's passwords using `passwd` ... I'm not sure what repercussions this would have if your authentication chain requires tokens, but this should do the trick if you only auth via LDAP

Comment: There are various bug reports relating to this, and it has nothing to do with the slapd setup.  This is the report with the most recent activity: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=588434

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following configuration for PAM passwd support:

```
password    requisite      pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3  
password    sufficient     pam_ldap.so try_first_pass use_authtok  
password    sufficient     pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok use_authtok try_first_pass  
password    required       pam_deny.so
```

Also remember that ACLs should be configured from most specific to least specific, because the first matching entry wins. Mine looks like this:

```
access to attrs=userPassword
    by dn="cn=admin,dc=hell" write
    by set="[cn=admins,ou=access groups,ou=groups,dc=hell]/memberUid & user/uid" write
    by anonymous auth
    by self write
    by * none
```

(BTW, I'd rather recommend original OpenLDAP administration guide than the Zytrax book; the book uses the guide as a source anyway, but frequently introduces errors while it strays away from the original text.)